# Remove switch in more generic way

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, design-patterns, factory

I encountered this class:

```
public class CommandFactory
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, ICommand> commands;
    private readonly IPrinterEmulator printerEmulator;

    public CommandFactory(IPrinterEmulator printerEmulator)
    {
        commands = new Dictionary<string, ICommand>();
        this.printerEmulator = printerEmulator;
    }

    public ICommand GetCommand(string cmdStr)
    {
        ICommand command;

        if (commands.ContainsKey(cmdStr))
        {
            command = commands[cmdStr];
        }
        else
        {
            command = GetConcreteCommand(printerEmulator, cmdStr);
            commands.Add(cmdStr, command);
        }

        return command;
    }

    private ICommand GetConcreteCommand(IPrinterEmulator printerEmulator, string commandStr)
    {
        return commandStr switch
        {
            "SetJob" => new SetJobCommand(printerEmulator),
            "GetJob" => new GetJobCommand(printerEmulator),
            _ => new NotReconizeCmd(printerEmulator),
        };
    }
}
```

I am wondering why the dictionary in class constructor wasn't prepopulated in fashion `Dictionary<string,Func<ICommand, string>> selector`, but rather using get command to gain reference to implementation?

I have feeling that there has to be more appropriate approach and I am sure that switch statement can be completely removed in this way. Your opinion?

Thank you in advance

Comment: why you don't like Switch operator? XD

Comment: @hamaronooo because it is something which doesnt belong to OOP and it is IMHO part of infrastructural stuff in code

Comment: It's a factory class; ultimately it's purpose to encapsulate navigating the odds and ends needed to provide an instance, so that the rest of the system doesn't have to be concerned with it.  Not not clear why this would be an affrond to OOP?

Comment: I think the switch can be replaced with chain-of-responsibility pattern

Comment: This switch should be placed inside your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) (the startup infrastructure), but that's unlikely the case since you are missing an `ICommandFactory` abstraction. If you add such abstraction, you can move the `CommandFactory` implementation into the Composition Root. It's perfectly fine to have switch case statements like these inside your Composition Root.